# How to download PDF from Spring REST service using Postman

Tags: spring-boot, postman

I have a Spring based Rest service which gives PDF as response. With my below code I can able to get the PDF content as binary values in my postman. My problem is to download it as attachment when I call the service.

To achieve this do i need to make any change in code or in Client.

```
@GetMapping(value="/getUserpdf")
    public ResponseEntity<Resource> getUserInfo(@RequestHeader(name="reqHeader") Map<String, String> reqHeader,
                                                  @RequestParam(name="userId",required=true) String userId){

        MetaInfo metaInfo = getHeaderValues(reqHeader);

        //To get Actual PDF content as Bytes
        byte[] pdfBytes = getUserPdfService.getUserInfo(metaInfo,userId);

        ByteArrayResource resource = new ByteArrayResource(pdfBytes);

        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.add("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate");
        headers.add("Pragma", "no-cache");
        headers.add("Expires", "0");
        headers.add(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment;filename=UserInfo.pdf");



        return ResponseEntity
                      .ok()
                      .headers(headers)
                      .contentLength(pdfBytes.length)
                      .contentType(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/octet-stream")).body(resource);
    }
```

Also I have registered my Converter

```
@Bean
    public HttpMessageConverters customConverters() {
        ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter arrayHttpMessageConverter = new ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter();
        return new HttpMessageConverters(arrayHttpMessageConverter);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example :

```
@GetMapping("/getUserpdf/{id}")
    @CrossOrigin
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource> downloadFile(@PathVariable(required = true, value = "id") Long id,@RequestParam(name="userId",required=true) String userId,HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException {

        //To get Actual PDF content as Bytes
        byte[] pdfBytes = getUserPdfService.getUserInfo(id,userId);
        if (Objects.nonNull(pdfBytes)) {
            String fileName = "UserInfo.pdf";
            MediaType mediaType = MediaType.parseMediaType("application/pdf");
            File file = new File(fileName);
            FileUtils.writeByteArrayToFile(file, pdfBytes); //org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils
            InputStreamResource resource = new InputStreamResource(new FileInputStream(file));

            return ResponseEntity.ok()
                    // Content-Disposition
                    .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment;filename=" + file.getName())
                    // Content-Type
                    .contentType(mediaType)
                    // Contet-Length
                    .contentLength(file.length()) //
                    .body(resource);
        } else {
            throw ResponseEntity.notFound().build();
        }
    }
```

NB: i am not sur about the mediaType but you can confirm if it's ok !

Comment: its working but this approach is creating file in my loacal as well. I am looking for somthing like when user hits my rest api in response i need to send PDF attachment without storing it in my local

Comment: this approach is creating file in my loacal as well !! not clear for me !

Comment: I have included FileOutputStream to write content to File that creates a PDF in my local workspace.No I have chnaged and used ByteArrayResource its works fine now.